# How to securely decrypt the video data in anroid without getting video data out from android app

Tags: android, security, video-streaming, drm, android-security

i am developing an android app that streams the encrypted vide content from server and decrypts in android. 
The streaming happens using temporary links.

The problems i found here was, when the key and temporary links are transmitted to android device, it is easy for an attacker to decrypt my data using key, temporory link and the alogorithm which was already in apk file (decryption algorithm can be revealed by reversing the apk file).

Note :- Here RSA like algorithms cannot be used because the decryption is happening in client side

Is there a way to decrypt the data in android without revealing the security key and alogrithm in apk file ?

Comment: I'll assume you've heard of [Widevine](https://www.widevine.com/). If you want a bit more detail into how Widevine uses the TEE, here is a [presentation on how Linaro tried to implement Widevine](https://connect.linaro.org/resources/las16/las16-406/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the core functionality that a DRM system bring to media protection.

Most DRM's use the same well known, open AES encryption algorithm supported by pretty much every device and often in the HW for better performance, so the thing that they add, and generally in a proprietary way, is the secure exchange of the key between the server and the client - exactly the vulnerability you have identified.

As noted, the different mechanisms are proprietary to the DRM systems usually, but at a very high level what they do is encrypt the key itself with a mother DRM key which is uniquely associated with the client, andusually in the hardware or in the TEE for the higher security levels of DRM.

For Android, as @Morrison says in the comments, the native DRM is Widevine, although you can sometimes find support for other DRMs also, although these are often software based rather than being tied to the HW.